# Extract a subset of an object as string

Tags: python, string, pandas

l want to extract only  `1841729699_001` for my variable.
the type of my variable is an object as follow :

```
coords[3]
1    1841729699_001
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

Then l tried to convert it to string :

```
str(coords[3])
'1    1841729699_001\nName: 3, dtype: object'
Then l tried 

X=str(list(coords[3])).replace('[','').replace(']','')
```

which prints

```
"'1841729699_001'"
```

But when l save in a file for instance :

```
import cv2
cv2.imwrite(str(X) + ".png",  image)
```

or

```
cv2.imwrite(X+ ".png",  image)
```

it save the image as follow :

```
'1841729699_001'.png
```

However l'm looking for this format

```
  1841729699_001.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.item`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html) for return from one item `Series` scalar:

```
coords[3].item() + ".png"
```

Or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) which return scalar too:

```
coords.loc[1, 3] +  ".png"
```

Sample:

```
coords = pd.DataFrame({3:['1841729699_00']}, index=[1])
print (coords)
               3
1  1841729699_00

print (coords[3].item() + ".png")
1841729699_00.png

print (coords.loc[1, 3] +  ".png")
1841729699_00.png
```

---

In your solution add `strip`:

```
X=str(list(coords[3])).replace('[','').replace(']','').strip("'")
```